# Software for streaming a video in an infinite loop

Tags: windows, gratis, webcam

I'm looking for a software that is able to create a video stream. I'm involved in sort of a game, where it'll be necessary for contenders to view an infinite loop where in a post-it is written a password that they'll need to catch. In order to do this, I'd need something that is able to elaborate this video in an infinite loop, and is able to stream this on a specific port. Does anybody know any solution of this kind? Possibly freeware.

I'd appreciate any input you might have.

Comment: VLC can do it.  Including a built-in http streaming server.

Comment: Thanks ivanivan. Do you think it's possible even to zoom in or pan within the video? Or should I use different approaches in order to achieve this?

Comment: If you are repeatedly looping a static video, then yes, your zoom and pan needs to be done while making the movie.

Comment: Thanks ivanivan. I managed to do it with VLC. If you want, you may post it as an answer and I'll grant it to you. Thanks and Regards, Alessandro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VLC can do this - it can loop the input, and has its own built in http streaming server.  Only thing is your panning and zooming, etc. will need to be done to the video before you start streaming.